# С какой целью используется «симметрия» при вставках из тире?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, вставная-конструкция

В **[справочнике Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=123) («Вставные конструкции» — пункт 4-4)** сказано так:

> Следует, впрочем, заметить, что часто встречается своеобразная «симметрия» знаков (постановка запятой перед вторым тире, если перед первым тире стоит запятая):
>
> *Когда я стану умирать, — и, верь, тебе не долго ждать, — ты перенесть меня вели в наш сад* (Л.);
>
> *Когда Косте, сиротке-то, пошёл девятый годок, — а я в ту пору уже невестой была, — повезла я его по всем гимназиям (Ч.)*;
> *Когда всё кончилось, — а бой длился около часу, — начдив сел на коня и шагом поехал по равнине (А. Т.)*;
>
> *Осенью, когда поспевали яблоки, — яблоневые деревья были гордостью семейства Поповых, — Анатолий обычно спал на топчане в^саду, чтобы мальчишки не покрали яблок (Ф.)*.

У меня есть версия причины такой симметрии: если вставка относится сразу и к предыдущей, и к следующей части, но структура требует запятой, то ставим с двух сторон, чтобы показать отнесëнность вставки к двум частям.

Правильная она или нет — неизвестно, но если так, то третий и четвертый пример этому не соответствуют. Обе вставки относятся к предшествующим придаточным частям.

**В общем, мои два самых главных вопроса: с какой целью используют симметрию знаков и когда еë можно использовать вообще?**

Comment: Хороший вопрос. Вижу основания для второй запятой только в 1-ом примере (обособление "тебе не долго ждать"). В остальных случаях это выглядит ошибкой. Запятые с длинным тире встречаются на стыке обособлений с оборотами и в прямой речи. А тут вообще не найти повода.

Comment: На вопрос о правилах Розенталя (относительно классики!) может только Грамота ответить. Лучше там  спросите.

Comment: @Sharon Не знаю, как вам ответить на это. Думаю, вы и сами догадаетесь, как я хочу ответить вам.

Comment: Я же не экстрасенс с дипломом, а только учусь) Так что уж ответьте. Что имел в виду Розенталь? Почему классики "ошиблись" и не по правилам написали?  Помните у Пушкина:  "Зачем крутится ветр в овраге, Подъемлет лист и пыль несет, Когда корабль в недвижной влаге Его дыханья жадно ждет?"

Comment: Это как раз про классиков, вот зачем так пишут?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Своеобразная «симметрия» сама себя и объясняет: для красоты, глазу чтоб приятно было!

Розенталь не случайно же её закавычил.

Использовать можно когда заблагорассудится, если не подневолен. То есть когда сам хозяин текста и никому не подотчётен.

Comment: Ладно. Раз Розенталь не сказал когда, значит, наверное, так и есть.

Comment: Максимка, не сомневайся во мне — у меня практика огромнющая. )))

Comment: Как скажете, спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 2):

```
  Это как раз про классиков, вот зачем так пишут?
```

***Красота*!)** Я тоже люблю все красивое, в том числе красивую **графику**, и  учитываю при решении задач с возможностью **выбора.**

Но здесь еще важно другое... Знак должен иметь **смысл,** это как бы ***нотный знак*** для произношения, для **мелодики речи.**

Вставка произносится с **измененным** темпом, с **понижением** тона — это особый речевой план. Мы уходим туда, а потом возвращаемся в основной текст.

**Симметричная** вставка — это  **одинаково** расположенные  паузы, несимметричный знак — паузы **смещены,** они обозначают **отнесенность** вставной конструкции к правой или левой части.

В правилах это **отражено**, но в некоторых случаях мы видим **расхождение**: несимметричный по правилам знак автор оформил как **симметричный**. Ведь автор **пишет как слышит**, а не только по правилам.

Comment: Ваш вариант тоже подходит. Всë-таки, думаю, решение зависит от автора, как написано в ответе выше. Но голос я поставлю (а точнее, уже давно поставил).

Comment: У нас с Галиной одинаковые ответы, только разными словами. Приемка для меня не важна, отвечаю ввиду давности и важности темы.

Comment: There's far better.

Comment: Не надо изменять прием ответа. Пожалуйста, верните обратно.  Вашего голоса мне вполне достаточно.